# How use load field one2many by context

Tags: odoo-8

see this exemple:   context="{'field_child_M2o':[parent.field_parent_M2o]}", i want load all values in field_parent(this field was filting ago) to field_child.
can one help me?.

Comment: Please describe your question, so we can understand.

Comment: my code python: demande_id = fields.Many2one('gmat.demande',string='N° Demande',required=True) "I want load all values in lis_mat to class child codebarre" articles_ids = fields.One2many('gmat.articlemouv', 'arts_ids',string='Mouvement') lis_mat=fields.Many2many('gmat.nbien') @api.multi @api.onchange('demande_id') def list_mouv(self): {code func} code class child : arts_ids = fields.Many2one('gmat.mouvements',string='num') codebarre = fields.Many2one('gmat.nbien')                                                     i want load all values in parent lis_mat M2o to field codebarre M2o